# Building nlohmann/json as a bazel library gives 'nothing to build' error

Tags: c++, bazel, nlohmann-json

I have a very simple bazel project where I'm trying to add https://github.com/nlohmann/json as a dependency. To accomplish that, I cloned the `json` repo locally and added a `BUILD` file in the repo's root dir to generate a `cc_library` containing the single include `json.hpp` file. But when I build that, it always complains that there is nothing to build.

```
├── json
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── // all files under nlohmann/json repo.
├── myproject
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── Main.cpp
└── WORKSPACE
```

json/BUILD:

```
cc_library(
    name = "json",
    hdrs = ["single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp"],
    includes = ["json"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Building the above succeeds but there is no library generated. Notice '(nothing to build)' message in the output.

```
bazel build :json
INFO: Analyzed target //json:json (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //json:json up-to-date (nothing to build)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.065s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

myproject/Main.cpp:

```
#include <single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp>

int main() {
    ...
}
```

myproject/BUILD:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["Main.cpp"],
  deps = [ "//json:json"]
)
```

`myproject` Build error:

```
myproject/Main.cpp:1:44: fatal error: single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Any ideas what am I missing here? My goal is to consume the `json` repo as a dependency in my bazel project `myproject`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to fetch external dependencies using `http_repository`/`git_repository` mechanism, because they do not clutter the history of the repo, they are easier to update and they are not even fetched, if you do not build anything, which depends on it.

```py
# /WORKSPACE file
http_archive(
    name = "com_github_nlohmann_json",
    build_file = "//third_party:json.BUILD", # see below
    sha256 = "4cf0df69731494668bdd6460ed8cb269b68de9c19ad8c27abc24cd72605b2d5b",
    strip_prefix = "json-3.9.1",
    urls = ["https://github.com/nlohmann/json/archive/v3.9.1.tar.gz"],
)
```

```py
# /third_party/json.BUILD file
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

licenses(["notice"]) # MIT license

cc_library(
    name = "json",
    hdrs = ["single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp"],
    strip_include_prefix = "single_include/",
)
```

And then:

```py
cc_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["Main.cpp"],
  deps = [ "@com_github_nlohmann_json//:json"]
)
```

```cpp
// Main.cpp file
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
```

Comment: This works! Other than loading `http_archive` module in workspace file, another change needed was to add an empty BUILD file in `third_party` folder otherwise bazel refuses to build and complains about no BUILD file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `cc_library` has no [`DefaultInfo.files`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/DefaultInfo.html#files), so when you specify its target on the command line Bazel doesn't know what things to build. Try `bazel build :main` to build your binary instead.

Also, `cc_library` itself does have [output groups](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#requesting-output-files). Try something like `bazel build :json --output_groups=dynamic_library` to get the library resulting from building its source files.

Note that in general, you should create a [`cc_binary`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary) for any outputs from your build. Even if you want a shared object, create a `cc_binary` with a name ending in `.so` instead of using `cc_library` alone. The `dynamic_library` output doesn't handle transitive dependencies (although I guess that doesn't really matter for this library, which has no dependencies anyways).

Comment: `output_groups=dynamic_library` didn't seem to do anything. But I added `strip_include_prefix` in `json:BUILD` and fixed the import in my Main file after which the main target is compiling fine now.