# How to compile nlohmann json library (header-only) with a C++ project using Bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel, nlohmann-json

I am trying to use the nlohmann json library in a C++ project compiled with Bazel. I am wondering how to include the library. The [documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#integration) reads:

> "json.hpp is the single required file in single_include/nlohmann or released here. You need to add
>
> #include <nlohmann/json.hpp>  using json = nlohmann::json;
>
> to the files you want to process JSON and set the necessary switches
> to enable C++11 (e.g., -std=c++11 for GCC and Clang)."

The documentation only provides further instructions on how to compile using CMake. I am wondering how I can add this library to my Bazel C++ project. I created a folder named "nlohmann" in my working directory and copied over json.hpp into the folder, but that did not compile correctly. I am wondering if I needed to include some repository link or add some dependency in the Bazel BUILD file?

Comment: All you need to do is to add the path of the nlohmann JSON file into your build system include-path.

Comment: Since there are more than one `json.hpp`, you should make sure to pick `./single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp`

Comment: [You can consult the docs on how to add an include directory using bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/cpp-use-cases.html#adding-include-paths).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Do I just copy over the file to a local directory and include that? Or is there a way to include the file that's in the online repository without having to download it?

Comment: @AmyLi It's easiest to download it or clone the whole repo

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67279332/4638604

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building nlohmann/json as a bazel library gives 'nothing to build' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273867/building-nlohmann-json-as-a-bazel-library-gives-nothing-to-build-error)